# Превышено максимально допустимое время выполнения, помогите оптимизировать

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

google script spreadsheet

Пытаю создать матрицу, если массив данных маленький то работает все замечательно, естественно если он превышает 800 строк и более упираюсь в ошибку "Превышено максимально допустимое время выполнения".
Не эффективно создаю матрицу:

```js
var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(); //понимаем какой лист открыт
var toAddArray = []; //создаем пустой массив будем в него складывать серийники
  for (i = 1; i <= s.getLastRow()+1; ++i){ //начинаем перебирать весь столбик с значениями, шапку игнорируем
  var numbr = s.getRange(i,4); //определяем каждую ячейку как область (интересная 4 колонка)
   var Valus = numbr.getValues().toString(); //получаем значение каждой ячейки

    //каждое полученное  значение фильтруем по какой-то маске
  var newznach = Valus.replace(/\-/g, "").replace(/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][a-zA-Zа-яА-Я][a-zA-Zа-яА-Я]/g, "").replace(/[a-zA-Zа-яА-Я][a-zA-Zа-яА-Я]/g, "");
  toAddArray.push([i.toFixed(0),Valus,newznach]); //записываем данные в массив 0- номер строки, 1- исходныеданные, 2- "очищенные данные"
  }
```

В итоге на выходе имею матрицу:

```
{
номер строки, значение исходное, пофильтрованное значение
номер строки, значение исходное, пофильтрованное значение
номер строки, значение исходное, пофильтрованное значение
...
}
```

Можно ли как-то такой же массив получить без перебора?

Comment: `getRange` `setRange` в циклах - грех.

Answer (score 2):

```js
var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var data = s.getRange(1,4, s.getLastRow()).getValues();

var toAddArray = data.map(function(row, i) {
  var Valus = row[0].toString();
  var newznach = Valus.
    replace(/\-/g, "").
    replace(/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][a-zA-Zа-яА-Я][a-zA-Zа-яА-Я]/g, "").
    replace(/[a-zA-Zа-яА-Я][a-zA-Zа-яА-Я]/g, "");

  return [i.toFixed(0), Valus, newznach];
});
```